# JavaScript libraries to detect browser capabilities/plug-ins

Tags: javascript, browser, plugins

I'm trying to find a (preferably open source) JS library to determine as much information as possible about the user's Web browser environment. I know it's possible to get such data as:

- Screen resolution,
- User-Agent, Accept-Language and other preferences usually sent in HTTP headers,
- Installed plug-ins (through `navigator.plugins`),
- Whether a particular browser feature is supported (SVG support, DOM capabilities)

What I'm looking for is a library which gathers such information and makes it available under a common cross-browser interface (there are a bunch of incompatibilties in how browsers report installed plugins, for example). I found [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) which can detect HTML5-related functionality, but similar projects which report more generic information, such as the data listed above, would be more useful.

Comment: Is this for capability testing, general analytics, or something else?

Comment: Mostly for general analytics but also to test whether built-in support for certain formats (such as PDF files through the Acrobat plug-in) is available. Another motivation is my own curiosity - to see what kind of data is being exposed through various browser interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely check out [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/), an academic study (with detailed explanation on theory, and supporting data) to determine what makes a browser installation unique.

Panopticlick uses a slightly outdated version of [this plugin detection script](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/)...