# Is it there any info for Browser plugin list?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, plugins, browser, firefox-addon

I trying to get browsers(IE, Mozilla, Chrome,safari)  plugins and extension list. But i get only few plugins and extension from registry. So is there any way to get all the list?Can i get common list of plugins used by this browsers,or anyone can share me the list of common plugins used by these browsers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this post and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436994/javascript-libraries-to-detect-browser-capabilities-plug-ins

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get this from JavaScript, or from native code on the PC?

Browsers do not consistently expose what plugins are installed to script. The navigator.plugins collection is exposed to JavaScript in Firefox and Chrome, but not all extensions are listed there. The collection is present but always empty in IE. In IE, the only real way to detect ActiveX controls is to try to create them and see whether it succeeds, and there's no way to detect non-content plugins (e.g. BHOs, toolbars, etc).

What is the overall goal that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to achieve it by javascript