# How to check add ons installed in browser using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, firefox-addon, clickonce

I want to run a click once application in Firefox browser for which the client browser should contain Microsoft .NET Framework Assistant add on installed.

Is there any way in jquery to detect if this add on is installed or not? If it is not installed I need to redirect the client to install the add on.

Comment: As far as I know ... no such way `:)`

Answer (score 0):

refer to this:

- http://odrademos.webs.com/jqueryplugindetection.htm
- [JavaScript libraries to detect browser capabilities/plug-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436994/javascript-libraries-to-detect-browser-capabilities-plug-ins)
- http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-browser-plugins/
- http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/ (i like this)

Comment: I already had checked the above mentioned articles. But my purpose is to detect the addons(Extensions) installed in browsers. The above mentioned articles shows how to detect the plugins installed not the addons

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a complete list just by using Javascript, but some Addons allow a check anyway.

> accessing the chrome://-protocol was considered a security risk and
>   therefore has been  [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Updating_web_applications_for_Firefox_3#section_7). Nonetheless you can still accomplish to detect
>   an extension with the image-load trick. Why? Because extension
>   developers may mark their extension as web-accessible setting the
>   property “contentaccessible=yes” inside the chrome.manifest file of
>   the extension. This is e.g. the case for the two famous plugins
>   Firebug and Web Developer Toolbar

source: http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-firefox-add-ons/

So can should download the [Microsoft .NET Framework Assistant Add-On](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/microsoft-net-framework-assist/) `.xpi`-file, unpack it and have a look inside the `chrome.manifest` file. It seems like that Add-On doesent allow nya content to be accessible.